# ParticleEffect Lib block data

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to use the [ParticleEffect Lib](http://bukkit.org/threads/1-8-particleeffect-v1-7.154406/) here.

I've got it working but there is one issue: when I set the material to wool and change the data to 15, it's still white not black wool.

```
BlockData bd = new BlockData(Material.WOOL, (byte) 15);
ParticleEffect.BLOCK_CRACK.display(bd, 0, 0, 0, 10, 50, center, 30);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
player.spigot().playEffect(location, effect, id, data, offsetX, offsetY, offsetZ, speed, particleCount, radius);
```

Using the `TILE_CRACK` effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in Spigot methods to play particle effects. You either do it with `Player` instance or `World` instance by using `spigot()` method.

Example:

```
 player.spigot().playEffect(location, effect, id, data, offsetX, offsetY, offsetZ, speed, particleCount, radius);
```

Replace `id` and `data` with block.

If you are not using 1.8 version of Bukkit (Spigot), then try using ProtocolLib to send packets with particles.

Comment: This does not answer to the question because the built-in method looks the same as that in the `ParticleEffect` class.

Comment: it also takes me back a step it plays a sound while the current method i have doesnt